# Select query with two IN (list) parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Using the following table how can I write a single mySql query that would extract the rows of the matching pairs?

I need to grab the rows of matching ID/rID pairs: [10,1002], [14,1003], [28,1001], [40,1002]

```
myTable
ID    rID   rName
------------------
1     1001  ThisName
10    1002  ThatName ***
10    1001  SomeName
11    1001  OtherName
14    1003  NewName  ***
14    1001  CrazyName
21    1003  OldName
28    1001  GoodName ***
28    1002  SimpleName
31    1003  BadName
40    1002  GreatName  ***
50    1004  TerribleName
60    1001  BlahName
```

The rows with *** are the ones I want to extract.  I was trying to the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID IN (10,14,28,40) AND rID IN (1001,1002,1003)
```

but that was also returning pairs [10,1001], [14,1001] and [28,1002].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` with tuples:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (id, rid) in ( (10, 1001), (14, 1003), (28, 1001), (40, 1002) );
```

You can also express this using explicit comparisons:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (id = 10 and rid = 1001) or
      (id = 14 and rid = 1003) or
      (id = 28 and rid = 1001) or
      (id = 40 and rid = 1002);
```

Comment: @rolinger note that MySQL seems not to optimise this terribly well

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - nice!  Thanks....I didn't know you could do that.  The name is called `tuples` though?  Huh...